# How to read a .txt file into a Structure in C

Tags: c

After reading through other examples here on stack overflow, i'm confused as to where i'm going wrong with my code. I'm trying to read the file and store the 3 pieces of information from each line as data in a struct

e.g.
(**startTown endTown energyExpended**) would be (**York Hull 60**) for the first line

and then this would be stored in the array **allTowns[1024]**

any help would be really appreciated, thank you :)

[This is the text file i'm trying to read into the struct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjfab.png)

[This is a link to what the code looks like (is only a few lines)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2HDl.png)

**here is a post in plain text of my code**:

```
  struct intertownEnergy {
    char startTown[256];
    char endTown[256];
    int energyExpended;
  }

  allTowns[1024];

  int openEnergyFile(void) {
    FILE * energyFilePtr = fopen("energy.txt", "r");
    int i = 0;
    if (energyFilePtr == NULL) {
      printf("no such file.");
      return 0;
    }

    while (!feof(energyFilePtr)) {

      fscanf(energyFilePtr, "%s,%s,%d\n", & allTowns[].startTown, & allTowns[].endTown, & allTowns[].energyExpended);
      printf("energy test for each line: %d\n", allTowns.energyExpended);
    }

    return 0;
  }
```

**here is the text file:**

York    Hull    60
Leeds   Doncaster   -47
Liverpool   Nottingham  161
Manchester  Sheffield   61
Reading Oxford  -43
Oxford  Birmingham  103
Birmingham  Leicester   63
Liverpool   Blackpool   79
Carlisle    Newcastle   92

***SOLUTION***
People in the comments helped me to identify the solution to my problem, so I have edited the code and am posting the correct running code below:

```
struct intertownEnergy{
char startTown[256];
char endTown[256];
int energyExpended;

} allTowns[1024];


int openEnergyFile(void)
{
FILE* energyFilePtr = fopen("energy.txt","r");
int i = 0;
if (energyFilePtr==NULL){
    printf("the file doesn't exist");
    return 0;
}

while(!feof(energyFilePtr)){

    fscanf(energyFilePtr,"%s%s%d\n", &allTowns[i].startTown, &allTowns[i].endTown, &allTowns[i].energyExpended);
    printf("energy test for each line: %d\n", allTowns[i].energyExpended);
    i++;
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Don't link to pictures, post your code and your source here in plain text. You are welcome.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you already have?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of running your code through [this formatter](https://codebeautify.org/c-formatter-beautifier).

Comment: @Robert Harvey It says it expects an expression in the square brackets on line 23, (the fscanf line)

Comment: Ah, quite right.  It needs an index into that array, and you didn't provide one.

Comment: I wouldn't expect that to do much.  Each read from the file will overwrite the previous one.  Learn about arrays and how to use them: how to properly declare an array, how to traverse it with an index.

Comment: Also thank you for formatting for me

Comment: I see three mistakes. [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) Control the loop with `while(fscanf(...) == 3)`. Secondly, remove the commas and the `\n` from the format string (the text file has no commas).Third, you have not supplied an array index.

Comment: You need an index and to keep count of the Towns read so far. And wait until someone edit the input file and add Stanstead Abbotts, Great Amwell, Much Haddam, Saint Albans..

Comment: Yes, `%s` stops at a the first whitespace. If there is a town with two words you are in trouble and need to format the file with tabs or commas.

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you I have solved the problem, is there a way for me to post the solution should anyone else come across this thread and need help?

Comment: You can edit the question and add it, or self-answer.

Comment: `while(!feof(energyFilePtr))` cannot be good. You must check the value returned from `fscanf` instead.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Amongst other things, it is missing the needed `#include` statement(s) for the needed header file(s)

Comment: [why while(!feof(energyFilePtr)){ is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)